# Problems and doubts when using gcc's -shared and -pie options

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, executable, ld, undefined-reference

I want to generate a PIE file which can be executed normally and can be linked dynamically by other files, so I used gcc's `-fPIE`, `-shared`, and `-pie` options. But I meet some problems. I have 3 files as follows:

```
$ cat add.c
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

$ cat add.h
int add(int a, int b);

$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Result of add(1, 2): %d\n", add(1, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Then I generate `libadd.so` by follows command:

`gcc -fPIE -pie -shared -o libadd.so add.c`

and run it:

```
$ ./libadd.so
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Though it can not be executed normally, it can be linked dynamically:

`gcc -L. -ladd -o main main.c`

run it:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
Result of add(1, 2): 3
```

But if I change the order of options `-pie` and `-shared`, the situation has changed.

Generate `libadd.so` by follows command:

`gcc -fPIE -shared -pie -o libadd.so add.c`

and run it:

```
$ ./libadd.so
```

Because the main function does not have any operations, so there is no print. But when I want to link it, it doesn't work:

```
$ gcc -L. -ladd -o main main.c
/tmp/ccpimuON.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, I don’t understand why this is the case. I didn’t find any information that can help. And how can I achieve my goal? Executable and linkable.

Comment: `-pie` is on by default if I remember correctly (you can `-nopie` if you hate pie). It's the `-shared` option that is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: @kabanus Your link looks very useful, I will go check it out now, thank you.